# How do I get the secret key from an encrypted token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, authorization, backend

I have a node js app. I need to get the secret key from the generated token for using my indivually verification method. Is there any decoding token method or splitting secret key from the token method for JWT ? Because I am currently providing personal token production by sending an email address to header, I need a method that can take the secret key from token to prevent this. Here is my code.

Here is my token creation part in Login code section: (If password is true:)

```
 const secretKey= user.email;
 const token = jwt.sign({
    email:user.email,
    password: user.password

}, 
secretKey,
{
    expiresIn :"2h"
}
)
return res.status(200).send({ message: 'success', token: token});
```

And then in the middleware I use this code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
try {

const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, req.headers.user);
req.userData = decodedToken;
next();
}catch(error) {
return res.status(401).send({
message: 'Auth failed'
});
}
```

And my app.js:

```
 const checkAuth = require('../middleware/checkauth');
 router.get('/api/company',checkAuth,companyController.list);
```

**EDIT:** I have learned that there is no function in javascript that can decode the secret key of token. Secret key is created with special alghoritms.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot retrieve a secret key from an encrypted token because otherwise everyone can generate valid tokens for your app. You should save the secret on your local server and never expose it.
Then, when you call the `jwt.verify` method, you should pass the secret instead of `req.headers.user`